# Blueimp jQuery File Upload won't validate or resize client side images

Tags: jquery, validation, blueimp, image-upload

my code must be dodgy?. I can't seem to get the client side validation or image resizing to work. The server side is working great but I'd love to minimize bandwidth where possible.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

I've exhausted my skills on this one. I'm no pro but i need some help.

I'm using https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
```

````
                $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    // url: 'jQuery-File-Upload-10.2.0/server/php/files/index.php',
                    dataType: 'json',

                    options: {
                        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
                        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
                        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:

                        //By default, images are resized to FullHD (1920x1080
                        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                            .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
                        imageMaxWidth: 800,
                        imageMaxHeight: 800,
                        loadImageMaxFileSize: 10000,
                        imageMinWidth: 400,
                        imageMinHeight: 400,
                        imageCrop: false, // Force cropped images
                        // loadImageFileTypes: '/^image\\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/',
                        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,

                        processQueue: {
                            action: 'validate',
                            acceptFileTypes: '@',
                            disabled: '@disableValidation'
                        }
                    },

                    processActions: {

                        validate: function (data, options) {
                            if (options.disabled) {
                                return data;
                            }
                            var dfd = $.Deferred(),
                                file = data.files[data.index];
                            if (!options.acceptFileTypes.test(file.type)) {
                                file.error = 'Invalid file type.';
                                alert(file.error);
                                dfd.rejectWith(this, [data]);
                            } else {
                                dfd.resolveWith(this, [data]);
                            }
                            return dfd.promise();
                        }

                    },

                    progressall: function (e, data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                        $('#progress .bar').css(
                            'width',
                            progress + '%'
                        );
                    },
                    add: function (e, data) {
                        data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo($('#container'));
                        $('#overlay').show();

                        data.submit();
                    },
                    done: function (e, data) {
                        $('#overlay').hide();
                        $('#container p').remove(":contains('Uploading')" );

                        // data.context.text('Upload finished.');

                        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                            $('#progress .bar').hide();
                            $('<p/>').html('<img src="server/php/files/' +file.name + '"/>').appendTo($('#container'));
                            if (file.error) {
                                $('<p/>').text(file.error).appendTo($('#container'));
                            } else {
                                $('<p/>').text("OK!").appendTo($('#container'));

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });```
````